# Python simulation for solutions to the Allen-Cahn PDE

Tags: python, pde

Is there a Python library or already-written function that gives values for the Allen-Cahn equation? I'm trying to figure out how to simulate the solutions to the PDE described below, but don't know much about PDE's and how to go about it.

[link to equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rhkq.png)

Comment: There is not a Python library or function that gives values for the Allen-Cahn equation. However, there are several libraries that can be used to solve partial differential equations (PDEs), such as Sundials and SciPy. Additionally, there are several functions that can be used to approximate solutions to PDEs, such as the Python function "finite_difference".

Comment: Does this work even with PDE's that don't have an easily representable solution? I'm trying to make a plot of the allen-cahn equation but the solution isn't representable by elementary functions. It seems that sympy is limited to solving equation in such a manner.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "an easily representable solution".  If you mean a solution that can be represented in terms of elementary functions, then yes, sympy's solvers are limited to that.

If you mean a solution that cannot be represented in terms of elementary functions, then I'm not sure what the point of the plot would be.  I suppose you could create a plot of the numerical solution, but that would be more of a plot of the numerical method than of the actual solution.